# How to create mutiple modals / sliderover using tailwindcss with vue3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, inertiajs

Tailwindcss modal required to create "ref" for every modal/slideover but dataset has loop so can't able to create loop inside script method in vue 3 so without "ref" i want to create modal/slideover using loop.

I am trying to create modal/slideover using tailwindcss and vue3 with or without onclick. By default tailwindcss modal required to create "ref" for every modal/slideover but dataset has loop so can't able to create loop inside script method in vue 3 so without "ref" i want to create modal/slideover using loop. please help !

Code is here as example: inside the foreach loop. How to create like below

Loop example:

```
<button modal-target="modal1">Modal 1</button>
<div id="modal1">MODAL</div>
<button modal-target="modal2">Modal 2</button>
<div id="modal2">MODAL 2</div>
<button modal-target="modal3">Modal 3</button>
<div id="modal3">MODAL 3</div>
<button modal-target="modal4">Modal 4</button>
<div id="modal4">MODAL 4</div>
<button modal-target="modal5">Modal 5</button>
<div id="modal5">MODAL 5</div>
```